# Ubuntu 18.04 Ethernet Connection cutting off randomly after update from Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, 17.10, ethernet

I had used *Ubuntu 17.10* previously and when I updated to *Ubuntu 18.04*, I began to have trouble with my Internet Connection which is wired Ethernet. My experience with Ubuntu is very limited and here is the output for :

1.`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 06)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH LPC Controller (B250)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SMBus Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

2.`ifconfig -a`

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 4096
        inet 129.93.213.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 129.93.213.255
        ether 30:9c:23:3f:a4:e1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 29736  bytes 21675467 (21.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14893  bytes 2650128 (2.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 121  base 0x5000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6366  bytes 711610 (711.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6366  bytes 711610 (711.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

3.`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 30:9c:23:3f:a4:e1
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.045.08-NAPI duplex=full ip=129.93.213.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:121 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df104000-df104fff memory:df100000-df103fff
```

What should be done to fix this ?

Comment: Please edit with elaboration of you problem - what specific kind of problem you have? Huge ping, connection drops, you can't connect via ssh?

Comment: The connection cuts out completely for a period(A few minutes mostly), I can't ping anything, can't get webpages to load up, etc. And then will come back after a while, stay fine for a little bit, then repeat.

Comment: seems like an issue with your router. Seems like it is overheated or overloaded, so it reboots, and thus you face connection drops.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible the issue resides outside of your Ubuntu machine. I've had this issue in the past and it ended up being a faulty port on my switch. Here's a few things you can try on that tangent:

1. Replace the Ethernet cable/make sure it's the correct cable for gigabit (Cat5e, Cat6).
2. Check other devices on your network for similar issues. If they are experiencing the same problem, it's likely the fault of either a switch or your router, depending on how your network is laid out.
3. Look at the output of `ifconfig -a` after the computer has been running for a couple hours. Check for any of the error categories: `dropped`, `overruns`, `collisions`, etc. These typically won't show up immediately after boot unless the problem is really prominent. Each of these categories indicates something going wrong (except collisions if your computer is connected to a hub) with a different aspect of your computer's connection.
4. Plug your Ubuntu machine into another port on your switch/router. Try to duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same network hardware and same problem. Running 16.04 LTS.

Have also cranked through a process of elimination, only noting fewer breaks while data is streaming, Ex. file transfer, VOIP call. Since I would rather be tortured than run Windows, finding a solution is not optional.

***Fix 1***

In System Settings | Software and Updates, on Ubuntu Software tab, be sure 'Proprietary drivers for devices' is checked. Then:

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
```

and reboot. This installs the Realtek driver, which works for some so posting here. Didn't work in my case so...

***Fix 2***

In router interface (if accessible), assign a fixed IP to the problem PC, then reboot router.

This had a stabilizing effect on the connection, but still getting some drops so searching on...

***Fix 3***

Found the problem: My ISP. Monitored the first machine with:

```
tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

Found that every time the disconnect happened, there was an entry:

> "...disconnecting connection 'Wired-default' for new activation
>   request."

But no "new activation request" was made!

So connected a second wired machine to the router and monitored it like the first. Found that the disconnects were timestamped the same. To verify, connected directly to the (bridged) modem, which eliminated the router as a possible cause.

Reported findings to ISP, they took action, and now everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

`driver=r8168 driverversion=8.045.08-NAPI`

You have installed `r8168-dkms` kernel package when using Ubuntu 17.10.

After upgrade it stayed there, but it is not needed any more.

Remove it by

```
sudo apt purge r8168-dkms
sudo modprobe -r r8168
sudo modprobe r8169
```

Your network adapter will be handled by in-tree `r8169` module, that should work well.

I came across this problem a couple of times already exactly with this upgrade on this adapter revision.